# Cycles - Alpha/Transparency Issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

I'm having an issue with alpha in a material. I have this cactus (imported from sketchfab) which has a material for the spikes scattered around. This material is applied to a mesh with faces going in all directions. This spike mesh intersects with the main cactus mesh, which I believe is causing the alpha of the spike material to create some glitchy transparency issue where the main mesh is being visibly 'eaten' away.

It's worth noting that this doesn't matter whether I'm using the texture alpha from the png or just applying alpha to the material overall. This combination of materials also displays as expected in Eevee so it seems to be a cycles specific issue!

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You are correct, it may be the intersection of the two meshes causing the problem. Is there a reason you need to use such a large, invasive mesh to get the spikes? Would it make sense to make one spike and instance it all over the surface using Geometry Nodes instead?

Comment: ohhh. I've figured it out. it was partially due to the intersection but more so due to the size of the scene, it seems. I'm trying to do a large desert scene (with large rock formations in the background as you can see. Kind of arbitrarily made the base plane 25000 x 25000, this appears to be causing a glitch where basic transparency results in refraction. If I paste the elements into a new file at origin - they render fine. Need to do some research on spatially large scenes, any pointers?

Comment: No specific pointers, really, just that it is true that blender suffers from floating-point precision errors at large distances from the origin. I don't know exactly where the line is, but I've heard estimates as conservative as 5000 units. before some precision becomes lost. I'm not sure what the remedy is (if there is one) if you need an extremely large scene, only that people have tried to accomplish it by "fooling" blender with trickery, but did not succeed. Also, transparency is usually the first to suffer from loss of precision, unfortunately.